# CSS Vertical JQuery Menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, slide

Where I'm at currently - http://officialspeed.tk/projects/

ok to get a better understanding of what I'm trying to learn you can head [here](http://officialspeed.tk/projects/) to see where I'm at.

I wanna hover over the lists and have it so the background slides from being transparent to it's current background color from left to right.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**The CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:#222;}

a {
    transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;}

div#download a {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    color:#555;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px 5px 5px 0px;}

div#download a:hover {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    color:#FFF;}

div#navigation {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 16px #000;}

ul#nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50%;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;}

ul#nav li {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#666;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;
    margin:0px 0px 5px -40px;}

ul#nav li a {
    color:#999;
    text-decoration:none;}

ul#nav li a:hover {
    color:#FFF;}
```

**The index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Learning Project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="download">
        <a href="jquery-flash-like-menu.zip">Download Source!</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some code, markup or images describing your problem/question instead of giving external links. Those links could be broken some day.

Comment: If I understand well, you want that initially ther's no `li` background, but to slide it once the `li` is hovered , right?

Comment: Yeah roXon exactly. I added the code, with the background color I want when hovered.

Comment: Have you tried something already with jQuery? may I see the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/eUSNd/3/)

[play](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/eUSNd/3/show/)

Just appended a phantom DIV, pay attention in the CSS , now the `#nav ul` has a higher z-index than our phantom div that will act like a background.

It grabs the height and width of your 'li' element so you are free to change your CSS any time, and our phantom BG will adjust itself!

Comment: Such a simple effect yet I feel so dumb. Thanks