# JQuery Horizontal Sliding Background

Tags: jquery, menu, background, sliding

Does anyone know how to turn this horizontal? [CSS Vertical JQuery Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799716/css-vertical-jquery-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things that needed done. You should probably read up on CSS.

Here's horizontal.
http://jsfiddle.net/eUSNd/51/

basically I used `float:left` on the newly created style `#nav li` then added a min-width (so they would spread properly).

Then I had to resize the container divs. Absolute positioning everything is a very risky practice. Please look up positioning and floats.

Comment: Hey thank you. Yeah I know absolute positioning can kinda be risky with IE. So in order to have the jquery slide over each link you would have to edit the query?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eUSNd/53/ I cleaned up your CSS a little more and tweaked the javascript. For some reason it isn't staying with the parent element. It would probably be better to re-ask using this fiddle and code.